# SSH: Understanding Algorithm Negotiation

Tags: algorithm, ssh

I'm currently writing an ssh honeypot in Java as a personal project. I'm having trouble understanding the algorithm negotiation. To be precise, the structure of the received data from the client. Here is what I receive, with my personal annotations:

```
00 00 07 AC == packet length

08 == padding length

14 ==  SSH_MSG_KEXINIT

6C 31 89 77 EB 54 E1 8B D4 B1 35 08 FD 52 65 6E == cookie

00 00 00 D4 == string length
kex algorithms in byte form 

00 00 01 67 == string length
server host key algorithms in byte form

00 00 00 E9 == string length
encryption_algorithms_client_to_server in byte form

00 00 00 E9 == string length
encryption_algorithms_server_to_client in byte form

00 00 01 92 == string length
mac_algorithms_client_to_server in byte form

00 00 01 92 == string length
mac_algorithms_server_to_client in byte form

00 00 00 1A == string length
compression_algorithms_client_to_server in byte form

00 00 00 1A == string length
compression_algorithms_server_to_client in byte form

00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Information about the negotiation can be found here:
[rfc4253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#page-17)

There are two things I don't fully understand:

1. The padding: How is it calculated? According to [rfc4253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#page-7), there should be a random padding (8 bytes in this case). I don't see it anywhere. Moreover, the size of the packet length + padding length + payload + padding should be a multiple of 8, which isn't the case here. (?)
2. The packet length: If I just sum up everything after the packet length, I get 0x797. Adding the 8 byte padding (wherever it is), I get 0x79F. Am I correct in thinking that the languages for client->server and server->client, although not defined, still take 4 byte each? That gets me to 0x7A7. If I now add the boolean and the reserved 4 bytes (see [packet structure](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#page-17)), I finally get 0x7AC. Is that correct? That would mean the trailing zeros have the following structure:

   ```
   00 00 00 00 == length of string for language_client_to_server
   00 00 00 00 == length of string for language_server_to_client
   00 == boolean first_kex_packet_follows
   00 00 00 00 == reserved
   rest: garbage?
   ```